# Using NDSolve to solve not quite Stefan-like problem

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a moving boundary PDE for a function $u(x,t)$ between $x=0$ and 
$x=s(t)$. The PDE is

$$ \partial_t u= u^2 \partial_x^2 u - \frac{\zeta}{2} x^3 \partial_x (u/x^2)$$

(1)

with the parameter $\zeta\ge 0$.  In rescaled variables, $\xi\equiv x/s(t)$ and $u_{\xi}(\xi,t)=u(x,t)$, the PDE is given by

$$\dot{u_{\xi}}=\xi\,\frac{\dot{s}}{s} u_{\xi}'+ \frac{u_{\xi}^2 \, u_{\xi}''}{s^2}
-\frac{\zeta}{2} \xi^3 (u_{\xi}/\xi^2)'$$

(2)

with dot denoting derivative wrt to $t$ and primes with respect to $\xi$. The problem is subject to the regularity condition $u(0,t)=0$ and boundary condition $u_{\xi}(1,t)=1$. The initial condition is $u_{\xi}=1$ everywhere except $u_{\xi}=0$ at $x=0$. The equation to complete the system (i.e., to determine the front position $s(t)$) is

$$u_{\xi}'(1,t)=s(t)^2 \left(1-\frac{\zeta}{2}-\zeta \ln{(s(t)/R)}\right)$$

(3)

where $R$ is some large distance cutoff. My point in solving the problem was to verify that it relaxes to a known steady state solution.

The problem is not quite Stefan-like, since the equation to determine $s$ does not involve its time derivative.  However, my initial attempt to solve this system in Mathematica
was to adapt Stefan code provided in a a previous thread.  To do this, I first used the fact that $\dot{u_{\xi}}(1,t)=0$, and then using (2) and (3), obtain an equation for  $\dot{s}(t)$:

$$\dot{s}=\frac{\zeta}{2}\,s- \frac{\frac{u_{\xi}''(1,t)}{s^2}+\zeta}{s (1-\frac{\zeta}{2}-\zeta\ln{(s(t)/R)}}$$.
(4)

Here is the code I used:

```
n = 100;(*100*)
\[Delta]\[Xi] = 1/n;
\[Zeta] = .1;
R = 100;

ClearAll[dv, t, paddedgrid];
dv[v_List] := With[{s = First@v, u = Rest@v, \[Xi] = N@Range[n - 1]/n},
   With[{paddedgrid = 
      Join[{First[\[Xi]] - \[Delta]\[Xi]}, \[Xi], {Last[\[Xi]] + \
\[Delta]\[Xi]}],
     paddedu = Join[{0}, u, {1}]},
    With[{d1 = 
       NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, paddedgrid(*,
         "DifferenceOrder"\[Rule]1*)][paddedu],
      d2 = 
       NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, paddedgrid(*,
         "DifferenceOrder"\[Rule]2*)][paddedu]},
     With[{
       d1main = d1[[2 ;; -2]],
       d2main = d2[[2 ;; -2]],
       d1edge = d1[[-1]],
       d2edge = d2[[-1]]},
      With[{ds = - ((d2[[-2]]/s^3 + \[Zeta]/s)/(
           1 - \[Zeta]/2 - \[Zeta] Log[s/R])) +  \[Zeta]/2  s},
       Prepend[
        u^2 d2main/s^2 - \[Zeta]/
          2 (\[Xi] d1main - 2 u) + \[Xi] ds d1main/s, ds]]]]]
   (*d1=ListCorrelate[{-0.5,0,0.5}/\[Delta]\[Xi],#]&,d2=
   ListCorrelate[{1,-2,1}/\[Delta]\[Xi]^2,#]&*)
   ];
s0 = 1/100;
v0 = Flatten@Prepend[ConstantArray[1, n - 2], {s0, 1/100}];
(*v0=Flatten@Prepend[(1-Exp[-1 #])&@(N@Range[n-2]/n),{s0,0.0001}];*)

sol = NDSolve[{v'[t] == dv[v[t]], v[0] == v0}, v, {t, 0, 100}(*,
    WorkingPrecision\[Rule]25,MaxSteps\[Rule]\[Infinity]*)][[1, 1, 2]];
```

and then

```
Needs@"DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`";
values = InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid@sol;
valu = Transpose@
     Join[{#[[2]](*-2 \[Delta]\[Xi] #[[1]]*)}, 
      Rest@#, {1 #[[1]]/#[[1]]}] &@
   Transpose@InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid@sol;
vals = InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[sol][[All, 1]];
t = Flatten@InterpolatingFunctionGrid@sol;
\[Xi] = Range[0., n]/n;
s = ListInterpolation[vals, t];
u\[Xi] = ListInterpolation[valu, {t, \[Xi]}];
u = If[#2 < s[#], u\[Xi][#, #2/s[#]], 1.] &;
```

Now, if the parameter $\zeta$ is set to 0, all is fine.  The problem amounts to nonlinear diffusion and the solution relaxes to $u=x$ and $s=1$.  However, with any $\zeta>0$ the code does not find a steady-state solution, and I'm pretty sure it has to do with numerical instability (likely owing to the $\frac{\zeta\,s}{2}$ term in (4)).  A clear sign that there is numerical error in  the solution resulting from my code, is that (3) is not obeyed:

[image]

The blue curve is $u_{\xi}'(1,t)$; the yellow one is $s(t)^2 (1-\frac{\zeta}{2}-\zeta \ln{(s(t)/R)}$. At short times, they agree, but then rapidly diverge.

I realize that this is a somewhat complicated problem, but does anyone have suggestions to minimize/eliminate this error?  Is there a simpler way to implement the constraint given by Eq. (4)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the replacement of equation (3) by (4) give the correct result?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  A little bit of algebra shows that setting $\dot{u}_{\xi}(1,t)=0$ (which follows from the BC $u_{\xi}(1,t)=1$) in the PDE (2), and then using (3), leads to (4).  So, yes, I'm pretty sure that (2) and (3), together with $u_{\xi}(1,t)=1$ implies (4).

Comment: It would be better to use equation (3), time-differentiated.